# Angular 2 components as modules

Tags: angular

I saw in some [seed projects](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) and on videos that it makes sense to create modules(base and routingmodules) for each component. Unfortunately I can´t figure out why this makes sense.

e.g in the linked seedproject there is a home component which has a home module and a home routing module.

Can anyone explain the additional value?

Answer (score 0):

The value of modules and separate routes per module is the segmentation and separation of the application into smaller pieces grouped together as logical units. Routing for each modules becomes important when you have many modules and not everything is under the root of the application. Example: /home /users /categoreis/new. I would create separate modules for users and categories. Both will have their own routing modules to make them child routes of the main application module.

Comment: Is it one path in your Example? or two paths -> home/users and home/categories/new ?

Comment: /home is the root, that lives in the app module routes. Then /users/new/list, etc and categoires/new/list, etc are separate modules with sub-routes.